# 'firebase init' always leads to C:/Users/PC

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-cli

When I run the command:

```
PS C:\Users\PC\Desktop\Project> firebase init
```

it says:

```
You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

  C:\Users\PC
```

I have tried running it in C:\Users and it worked properly, it won't go anywhere farther than C:\Users\PC

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `firebase init`, then first thing is does is check parent directories for the presence of a hidden ".firebaserc" file to see if there is a project already created.  If the file isn't found, it will create a new project in the current directory.  If the file **is** found, it assumes you are working with an existing project in the stated folder.

You have a .firebaserc file in C:\Users\PC.  If this is not what you expect, and you don't actually have a project there, d then you should probably just delete that file and start over.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried to host it previously but it failed so i guess it started making a project and it was just there. Thank you again!